# Durable Function exception: "Unable to find an Azure Storage connection string to use for this binding."

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a Function App with a durable function (and some non-durable functions as well) and I'm getting an InvalidOperationException that says: `Unable to find an Azure Storage connection string to use for this binding.`

Here's the stacktrace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskExtension.GetOrchestrationServiceSettings (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskExtension.Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.IExtensionConfigProvider.Initialize (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.JobHostConfigurationExtensions.InvokeExtensionConfigProviders (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.JobHostConfigurationExtensions.CreateStaticServices (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.InitializeServices (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Utility.CreateMetadataProvider (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Utility.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 362)
  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost.LoadBindingExtensions (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Host\ScriptHost.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 966)
  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost.Initialize (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Host\ScriptHost.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 299)
  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHostManager.RunAndBlock (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Host\ScriptHostManager.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 177)
```

It appears to be the durable function that's complaining about the missing connection string. However, I do have the connection string populated in my AzureWebJobsDashboard app setting, so I'm not sure why it's failing.

Comment: You need to make sure that the storage connection string is provided for the "AzureWebJobsStorage" app setting.

Comment: Thanks, @LingToh, I mistook the Dashboard setting for the Storage one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(This question showed as not having an answer, so I'm taking Ling's suggestion and making it into a proper answer here)*

In addition to the `AzureWebJobsDashboard` app setting, you also need to specify your Azure Storage connection string in the `AzureWebJobsStorage` app setting. The latter app setting is required by a variety of Azure Functions features, including Durable Functions. It's okay for the two app settings to have the same connection string.

Answer (score 5):

As other answers have said, I was getting the exception due to the missing `AzureWebJobsStorage` connection string. The connection string was, however, present in the `appsettings.Development.json` file...

In order to get the Durable Function project to start up locally, the connection string needed to be in the `local.settings.json` file.

Comment: Yeah, same here: value was present in another config file but I wasn't using a local.settings.config on this project; added it and it's working again, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, John, adding local.settings.json resolved my issue. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue. Updated Nuget pacakges, adding extentions didn't work, but after John answer, I figured it out what I was missing.

[image: Error message]

It got resolved as I didn't have `local.settings.json` file so after adding it got resolved .

Attaching my local.setting.json which had the azureWebStotrage attribute.

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

I hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by an incorrect url.
If the emulator is stopped, you get back:
*"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"*
Refer to: [Create your first durable function in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-first-csharp?pivots=code-editor-visualstudio#prerequisites-1)

Resolutions:

1 - Ensure Azure Storage Emulator is working or restart it

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator.exe stop
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.10.0.0 command line tool
The storage emulator was successfully stopped.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator.exe start
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.10.0.0 command line tool
The storage emulator was successfully started.
```

2: Ensure url is correct. The output contains *several* urls, make sure you take the one for **statusQueryGetUri**, *(this is the most likely cause)*:

```
{"id":"57756e5133f047ed9213b3956c0268be",
"statusQueryGetUri":"http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/57756e5133f047ed9213b3956c0268be?taskHub=TestHubName&connection=Storage&code=Ruk2CuiKU7yk9GM1qjalxynMwk2Bx2/KOpz78lxmPa4cNb2AtDZppw==",
"sendEventPostUri":"http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/57756e5133f047ed9213b3956c0268be/raiseEvent/{eventName}?taskHub=TestHubName&connection=Storage&code=Ruk2CuiKU7yk9GM1qjalxynMwk2Bx2/KOpz78lxmPa4cNb2AtDZppw==",
"terminatePostUri":"http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/57756e5133f047ed9213b3956c0268be/terminate?reason={text}&taskHub=TestHubName&connection=Storage&code=Ruk2CuiKU7yk9GM1qjalxynMwk2Bx2/KOpz78lxmPa4cNb2AtDZppw==",
"purgeHistoryDeleteUri":"http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/57756e5133f047ed9213b3956c0268be?taskHub=TestHubName&connection=Storage&code=Ruk2CuiKU7yk9GM1qjalxynMwk2Bx2/KOpz78lxmPa4cNb2AtDZppw=="}
```

Working config file:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. Had to add `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",` to my local.settings.json file. This will start the emulator. The setting appeared empty at first.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after updating **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs** from Nuget packages, then "AzureWebJobsStorage" will be an empty string like

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
}
```

}

Then go to your

> local.settings.json

Then add this one

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
}
```

}

Hope it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

I've had everything needed and still getting the message. After 1 hour (or more) I got really pissed with the cause of it:

There is no specific error stating your local.settings.json is malformed, so I was simply missing a comma "," in my file after a rebase.

So, take another look at your local.settings.json, just to ensure everything is ok.